# Cannot update from OS X 10.11 to 10.11.1 - Stuck in loop

Tags: upgrade, mac-appstore, macos

On 2014 iMac, OS X El Capitan 10.11...

In App store, I select [Update] for OS X El Capitan Update 10.11.1
The option to restart is displayed. I select it. 
Then the message "Available updates have changed." is displayed.
I click [Show Details] option. 
Returns to App Store
Repeat...

Answer (score 1):

Although this answer is a single link, it goes directly to the [10.11.1 Update Installer download](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1845?locale=en_US), and does not rely on the App store. If you can boot your machine and use it normally, download this installer and ignore the App store for now. The .dmg size is 1.19GB.